# Creating new column by column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to create new column by using existing ones. I want to assign column name as value to corresponding row if that column has value (i.e not `NaN` values). I also need to exclude some columns for example in the sample dataframe `Column5` should be excluded. I couldn't come up with solution. How can I do it? **Note:** I know there isn't any overlapping values.

**Sample DataFrame:**

```
  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4 Column5
0     NaN      1.0      NaN      NaN       f
1     NaN      NaN      NaN      5.0     NaN
2     NaN      NaN      2.0      NaN       c
3       c      NaN      NaN      NaN       y
4     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       x
```

**Expected DataFrame:**

```
  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4 Column5   newcol
0     NaN      1.0      NaN      NaN       f  Column2
1     NaN      NaN      NaN      5.0     NaN  Column4
2     NaN      NaN      2.0      NaN       c  Column3
3       c      NaN      NaN      NaN       y  Column1
4     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       x      NaN
```

Comment: Which part specifically are you struggling with?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `DataFrame.notna` + `DataFrame.dot`:

```
c = df.columns.difference(['Column5'])
df['newcol'] = df[c].notna().dot(c).replace('', np.nan)
```

Result:

```
  Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4 Column5   newcol
0     NaN      1.0      NaN      NaN       f  Column2
1     NaN      NaN      NaN      5.0     NaN  Column4
2     NaN      NaN      2.0      NaN       c  Column3
3       c      NaN      NaN      NaN       y  Column1
4     NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN       x      NaN
```